# I'm a salaried employee, paid on the 1st of each month. My employer is 11 days late paying me. What are my rights?

Tags: professionalism, management, ethics, canada

I am a salaried employee that is usually paid on the 1st of each month. This was agreed upon in my employment contract. They cut a cheque for the 1st, but it bounced. They say funds are coming everyday but they haven't yet and it's now almost the 12th. It is causing me great stress. What are my rights and where should I go from here? I am located in Ontario.

Comment: I can't speak to your specific legal rights in Canada, but you have a really blatantly big red flag that you might not actually have a job much longer, as you might not have an employer much longer. In addition to direct recourse of trying to get paid as you are owed, you need to start looking for another job immediately.

Comment: Rights don't really mean much when the money simply isn't there to make payroll in the first place.

Comment: Rights aside, your best course of action is to start dusting off your Resume and looking into other opportunities. It may be that your employer manages to salvage the ship, but you don't want to be betting *your* livelihood on that.

Comment: @LorenPechtel normally unpaid salary is first in line in bankruptcy  - though id make sure I took my company laptop home with me every night just in case :-)

Answer (score 4):

Presuming you're paid after the fact, the first right you have is that they owe you your salary. So if on Feb 1st they pay for January , you worked January, that is a debt they owe you. The bad news is that you may be in line with a whole lot of other creditors.

So your second right is that you can demand they issue you an ROE (Record of Employment) to enable you to claim EI. If you want to stop coming to work since they aren't paying you, they would stop increasing their debt to you, and the EI payments may help you stay solvent. You could tell them you will come back when they have work for you and money to pay for it.

That's about it, really. And the problem is that depending on the reason for the cash flow crunch, withdrawing your services could make it worse. If you want to ask someone for an explanation so that you can decide whether to support them through this rough spot or not, go ahead and ask, but you may not get a useful answer.

Comment: Clarifying the first paragraph: You have the right to sue them for back pay, but if they really are having trouble with payroll they're on the edge of going bankrupt.

Comment: @keshlam Even if they do declare bankruptcy you want to be in line.

Comment: @Frisbee:  I'm not sure that you can influence your place in the line very much.  In the OP's shoes I'd be putting energy into getting another job lined up rather than into squeezing blood from a turnip.

Comment: @keshlam You need to get in line.  You imply not worth suing.  And employees are a priority in pay order.

Comment: Ok, points granted. But I think the better answer, unless you have a major cash or emotional stake in the business, is probably to get out before they owe you enough to be worth suing for.

Comment: An employee isn't in line with creditors.  And employee has first rights to get paid.  Not sure if there is anywhere in the world this isn't true but certainly for US and Canada.

Comment: @blankip: Actually, it depends. In Germany, for example, only payment for work done _after_ the declaration of bankruptcy enjoys special protection (_Masseverbindlichkeit_). "Old" outstanding payments are like any other debt. If the employee received their last salaries knowing their employer was already insolvent, the employee may even have to _pay back_ that salary (_Insolvenzanfechtung_, §130 InsO)!

Comment: From [PWC Canada](http://www.pwc.com/ca/en/services/insolvency-assignments/bankruptcy-faqs.html): *An employee is entitled to a priority claim for unpaid wages and vacation pay, which remain outstanding six months prior to the initial bankruptcy event or the date of receivership. The amount of the priority is limited to $2,000 per employee with an additional $1,000 for disbursements made by a travelling salesperson. The priority claim for unpaid wages does not include termination and severance pay.* (another paragraph at the link). So +1 to @keshlam.

Comment: These things apply if the company goes into bankruptcy, but there can be months of not paying bills without going into bankruptcy. During that time they can basically choose who to pay and who not. It's typically done based on what they will get for paying a debt, such as a supplier withholding new shipments. Once you've left, the priority of catching up on the debt to you will be very low. Once they are bankrupt, http://www.labour.gov.on.ca/english/es/pubs/bankruptcy.php may be helpful.

Comment: @if your not paying some one they have breached the contract - you are no longer employed

Answer (score 1):

Googling "canada wage nonpayment claim" Reveals this publication: [Canadian Government Wage Recovery](http://www.esdc.gc.ca/en/reports/labour_standards/wage_recovery.page).  [This](http://wiki.clicklaw.bc.ca/index.php/My_employer_isn't_paying_my_wages) also looks useful.  I suggest that you read them both.  I also suggest that you immediately follow the instructions given.  The longer you wait, the less chance you have of getting paid.

I don't know about Canada, but in the US wages take precedence over everything else, even the IRS.  To get out of paying wages in a bankruptcy, you'd have to have no assets.

Comment: I think taxes paid on behalf of employees to the IRS take absolute precedence, to the degree that having a limited company won't protect you from jail in bad cases. Of course these taxes are actually part of the employee's wages.

Comment: Yes indeed, but I meant to refer to taxes owed by the company to the IRS, not employee tax withholding.